# Detect which text "mode" (normal, italic, bold, etc.) is currently in use?

Tags: fonts, conditionals, small-caps

In my document, I'm often setting upper case words and abbreviations in small caps because it avoids breaking the flow (which upper case words does). Also, many words (like `CUDA`, for instance) are also entered as commands instead of directly as text.

Up to this point I have manually set these words in small caps where appropriate (like `\textsc{\cuda}`), but this becomes unnecessarily repetitive. What I would like to be able to do is to define a command like `\cuda` which prints `CUDA` in small caps where the text "mode" is normal roman, and sets `CUDA` in upper cases if the text mode is italics. The reason for doing this is the font I'm using doesn't support small caps in italics.

Hence I would like to be able to detect which text "mode" is currently in use, and act accordingly.

I've included a minimal example below to illustrate my point:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcase}

\newcommand{\cudaString}{CUDA}
\newcommand{\cuda}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\cudaString}}}

\begin{document}
Set \cuda in small caps here,
\itshape but do not set \cuda in small caps here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's little point in `\newcommand{\cuda}{\textsc{CUDA}}`, as it will appear in all caps anyway; it's probably `\textsc{cuda}`, isn't it?

Comment: Ah of course; I forgot that in my code I use `\MakeTextLowercase` and I wrote the example code just from memory.

Comment: So it would be better to show a *real* example, as solutions with `\MakeUppercase` might have problems.

Comment: Probably. I've updated the example accordingly.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163991/does-the-latex-kernel-define-font-shape-macros-that-expand-to-it-sc-etc

Answer (score 37, accepted):

LaTeX's 'New Font Selection Scheme' (NFSS) stores information about the font in a number of macros. The macro `\f@shape` stores the shape: `n` for upright, `it` for italic and `sc` for small caps. `\f@series` stores the series: `m` for mid-weight and `bx` for bold, while `\f@family` stores the family: something like `cmr` for roman, `cmss` for sanserif and `cmtt` for monospaced (it's dependent on the current font).

Thus you can test for small caps using

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IfSmallCapsTF}{%
  \ifx\f@shape\my@test@sc
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\my@test@sc}{sc}
\makeatother

 \IfSmallCapsTF{true-code}{false-code}
```

Comment: I would actually like to accept two answers - this on and egreg's - as I incorporated both to make a command which sets its argument in small caps if the current style is roman, fake small caps if it is italics, and otherwise just converts it to upper case.

Comment: I'm wondering... Do you really have to define a command that expands to `sc`? Or is that name already stored in some kernel macro?

Comment: @Jubobs That I know of `latex.ltx` doesn't provide any useful shortcuts for these. Of course, with an up-to-date engine you can use `\pdfstrcmp` or similar for the test (`\ifx` likely faster if used many times).

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks. I need to perform a test on the current font shape, but I was wondering whether I was "reinventing the wheel" by defining those macros.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to *fake* an italic small caps font:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SCorIT}[1]{%
  \ifdim\fontdimen\@ne\font>\z@
    \begingroup\check@mathfonts
    \fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont
    \MakeUppercase{#1}\endgroup
  \else
    \textsc{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\cuda}{\SCorIT{cuda}}
```

Depending on the font the result can turn out to be as desired. Beware that for bold face another test must be added.

[image]

If you use `\MakeLowercase` or **textcase**'s `\MakeTextLowercase` for defining the acronym, you should modify the definition into

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SCorIT}[1]{%
  \ifdim\fontdimen\@ne\font>\z@
    \begingroup\check@mathfonts
    \fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont
    \let\MakeTextLowercase\@firstofone % for textcase
    \let\MakeLowercase\@firstofone     % for standard LaTeX
    \MakeTextUppercase{#1}\endgroup
  \else
    \textsc{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

that will avoid accumulating case changes.

The example was generated with the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{textcase}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SCorIT}[1]{%
  \ifdim\fontdimen\@ne\font>\z@
    \begingroup\check@mathfonts
    \fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont
    \let\MakeTextLowercase\@firstofone
    \MakeTextUppercase{#1}\endgroup
  \else
    \textsc{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\cudaString}{CUDA}
\newcommand{\cuda}{\SCorIT{\MakeTextLowercase{\cudaString}}}

\begin{document}

\hbox{Set \cuda{} in small caps here,\strut}
\hbox{\itshape but do not set \cuda{} in small caps here.\strut}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please extend it to a minimal example? I keep getting compilation errors when I try to use it in my document.

Comment: My apologies. I must have done something wrong the first time, because now I got it running.

Answer (score 3):

Stealing a bit from the definition of `\em` (seen using `latexdef em`), we can create a command `\SCorUC` that typesets its argument in small caps or uppercase depending on context:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\SCorUC}[1]{\ifdim\fontdimen\@ne\font>\z@\MakeUppercase{#1}\else\textsc{#1}\fi}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\cuda}{\SCorUC{cuda}}
```