# Does the LaTeX kernel define font-shape macros that expand to `it', `sc', etc.?

Tags: fonts, conditionals, latex-base

I need to perform a test on the current font shape. More specifically, I need to detect whether the current font shape is italic or slanted.

Joseph Wright already provided a solution in his answer to [Detect which text "mode" (normal, italic, bold, etc.) is currently in use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31649/detect-which-text-mode-normal-italic-bold-etc-is-currently-in-use). For instance, if you define

```
\newcommand*{\my@test@it}{it}
```

then

```
\ifx\f@shape\my@test@it
```

will be true if the current font shape is italics.

However, as I'm trying to avoid code duplication as much as possible, I'm wondering whether there really is a need to define macros that expands to `it` (for italics), `sl` (for slanted), etc. I suspect there may already exist such macros, perhaps defined in the LaTeX kernel. Is that the case? If so, what are those macros called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose that you are looking for `\bfdefault`, `\itdefault` and stuff:

> ```
> $ for x in bf it sl md up rm sf tt; do texdef -t latex ${x}default; done;
>
> \bfdefault:
> \long macro:->bx
>
> \itdefault:
> \long macro:->it
>
> \sldefault:
> \long macro:->sl
>
> \mddefault:
> \long macro:->m
>
> \updefault:
> \long macro:->n
>
> \rmdefault:
> \long macro:->cmr
>
> \sfdefault:
> \long macro:->cmss
>
> \ttdefault:
> \long macro:->cmtt
> ```

Be careful since they are all `\long`.

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for, but `\slshape\ifx\f@shape\sldefault` fails. I guess it's got to do with this `\sldefault` being long whereas `\f@shape` isn't...

Comment: According to [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39450/why-dont-we-always-use-long-def-instead-of-def#comment79587_39451) by Joseph, I'm on the right track. I'll figure something out. I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: These are right only if not changed: you can't be sure that they'll _always_ expand in the desired way

Comment: @JosephWright Depends what's "right". They'll show if the current setting was accomplished by `\slshape`.

Comment: @tohecz Yes, but not if the current setting has absolute code `sl`, for example: depends what you want to test for

Comment: For information, I wanted to test whether the font shape was either italic or slanted, and apply some italic correction in that case. I don't really care what the names of those shapes are, but I wanted a robust solution. I ended up defining a long macro based on `\f@shape` and `\ifx` comparing it to both `\itdefault` and `\sldefault`. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can easily be extended to what you need

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\def\getFSh#1/#2/#3/#4\@nil{#4}
\def\getFSe#1/#2/#3/#4\@nil{#3}
\begin{document}
\itshape
\curr@fontshape --> \expandafter\getFSh\curr@fontshape\@nil

\slshape
\curr@fontshape --> \expandafter\getFSh\curr@fontshape\@nil

\bfseries
\curr@fontshape --> \expandafter\getFSe\curr@fontshape\@nil\relax, 
                    \expandafter\getFSh\curr@fontshape\@nil
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not a direct answer to my question, but still useful. Thanks.

Comment: @Jubobs See `nfssext-cfr` and `nfssext` for examples using this sort of approach.