# New character in section title

Tags: sectioning

With a lot of help from this site I have made some code for a new character ʾ (transcribed Arabic Hamza) consisting of a raised, small rotated c. This character needed special kerning for italic font for which I used some code from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31649/detect-which-text-mode-normal-italic-bold-etc-is-currently-in-use) question. After I added this I ran intro problems. The whole thing works fine for normal text, but when the character is put in a section command it gives errors. When I run the MWE below on sharelatex.com it gives `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.` When this character is in a section title in my larger project it gives `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=50
00]`.

How can I make this work for section titles as well?

Thanks.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% test for italicness
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IfItElse}{%
 \ifx\f@shape\my@test@it
   \expandafter\@firstoftwo
 \else
   \protect\expandafter\@secondoftwo
 \fi
}
\newcommand*{\my@test@it}{it}
\makeatother

% New character HAMZA
\catcode`ʾ=\active
\defʾ{\IfItElse{\kern.12em}{\kern.0em}%
    \textsuperscript{\protect\raisebox{1.1ex}{\rotatebox{180}{c}}}%
    \IfItElse{\kern-.1em}{\kern-.05em}%
    {}} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\textit{Liqāʾ al-yawn}

\section{\textit{Liqāʾ al-yawn}}
```

\end{document}

Comment: `\protected\def'{...}` if you plan to use it in a section title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commands such as `\rotatebox` are *fragile*, meaning that they are not safe for usage in moving arguments (sectional titles or captions).

The simplest workaround is to use

```
\protected\def'{%
  \IfItElse{\kern.12em}{\kern.0em}%
  \textsuperscript{\protect\raisebox{1.1ex}{\rotatebox{180}{c}}}%
  \IfItElse{\kern-.1em}{\kern-.05em}%
  {}%
}
```

so that TeX won't try expanding `'` when writing to auxiliary files.

Comment: You're going to end up in the acknowledgement section in my dissertation at this rate.

Comment: I'd prefer a beer when I'm around Sweden! My best wishes for your dissertation.