# Hook to add code when switching font faces?

Tags: fonts, horizontal-alignment, xecjk

The [`xeCJK`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xecjk) package provides a key-value option `xCJKecglue` which sets the horizontal space when transitioning between CJK script and Latin script. This transitional space usually ranges from <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>5</sub> to <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>4</sub> of an em. It is often desired to set `xCJKecglue + digit.width + xCJKecglue` equal to the width of a (square) ideograph, so that phrases like `第一章` and `第 1 章` (both meaning “Chapter 1”) occupy the same amount of space.

Unlike ideographs (usually designed in a *fixed* square), Latin fonts are usually *proportional*. Even if the digits are tabular/mono-spaced, they *can* have different widths under different weights (e.g., wider in boldface). I would like to add `\xeCJKsetup{ xCJKecglue = <glue> }` in an automatic way whenever the faces change (which concerns 4 usual faces in *both* the roman family and the sans family). Basically, I was wondering if `xCJKecglue` could be specified in a “face-aware” way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK} % loads fontspec internally

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola} % Latin fonts specification

% Regular and italic faces have digit width 556/1000
\xeCJKsetup{ xCJKecglue = {\hskip 0.222em plus 0.05em minus 0.05em\relax} }

% Bold and bold italic faces have digit width 574/1000
%\xeCJKsetup{ xCJKecglue = {\hskip 0.213em plus 0.05em minus 0.05em\relax} }

\begin{document}
\huge
\begin{tabular}{ll}
第一章\rule[-0.2em]{0.4pt}{1em} & \bfseries 第一章\rule[-0.2em]{0.4pt}{1em} \\
第1章\rule[-0.2em]{0.4pt}{1em} & \bfseries 第1章\rule[-0.2em]{0.4pt}{1em} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: misaligned]

Note: The above MWE is *minimal* so it is hard to observe the misalignment for the boldface. The misalignment would be much more visible when switching to the sans family (with a very different digit width of course).

---

**Previous attempt**: There is half a solution that I have used in the past: Without setting `xCJKecglue`, `xeCJK` will insert a *normal Latin space* by default. So in principle I could modify `\fontdimen2` through the `WordSpace` option of `fontspec`; that is, I could do something like

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}[
  UprightFeatures={
    WordSpace=...
  },
  BoldFeatures={
    WordSpace=...
  },
  ...
]
```

This works fine if the inter-word space is not distorted *too much* (e.g., when pairing Source Han Sans with FiraGO, I’d shrink the inter-word space to 85%–98%). But for most other pairings, Latin fonts usually need to be scaled up first, which leads to a distortion of inter-word space around 75% — this no doubt destroys the color of Latin phrases/sentences inserted into the document.

Comment: Perhaps [Detect which text "mode" (normal, italic, bold, etc.) is currently in use?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/31649) will help?

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you for the pointer. From what I can understand, the post provides a way to “detect” current face. Any idea on “adding something to a hook (that probably does not exist)”? BTW, I’ve added my previous attempt which is to distort the normal Latin space (not recommended TBH).

Comment: Would the Unicode fullwidth digits, such as １ (U+FF11), work for you?

Comment: There are other packages that make this task simpler, but I don’t know if that’s relevant to you.

Comment: @Davislor I'd like to stick with ASCII digits if possible as they will be rendered in Latin fonts instead of CJK fonts.

Answer (score 3):

The solution consists of 3 parts.

**First**, [Detect which text “mode” (normal, italic, bold, etc.) is currently in use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31649), as pointed by @AlanMunn (thanks!), provides a way of *identifying* the current font attributes. Some nested conditionals can be used to treat the different faces separately. I’ll use the XeTeX primitive `\strcmp` to perform string comparison. The order of logical tests should be `\f@family`, then `\f@series` and finally `\f@shape`, with decreasing probabilities of different digit widths.

```
\newcommand*\setCJKecglue{%
  \ifnum\strcmp{\f@family}{\rmdefault}=0 %
    % Code for the roman family
    % \ifnum\strcmp{\f@series}{\mddefault}=0 %
    %   \ifnum\strcmp{\f@shape}{\updefault}=0 %
    %     % Code for roman regular
    %   \else
    %     % Code for roman italic
    %   \fi
    % \else
    %   \ifnum\strcmp{\f@shape}{\updefault}=0 %
    %     % Code for roman bold
    %   \else
    %     % Code for roman bolditalic
    %   \fi
    % \fi
  \else
    \ifnum\strcmp{\f@family}{\sfdefault}=0 %
      % Code for the sans-serif family
    \else
      % Code for the mono-spaced family
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

**Second**, we can then add the nested conditionals to the hook provided by the [`everysel`](https://ctan.org/pkg/everysel) package. Namely, `\EverySelectfont{\setCJKecglue}`.

**Third**, although `xeCJK` can handle various spacing issues, there are exceptions. One such exception is that phrases like `图~\ref{fig:example} 展示了` (meaning `Figure~\ref{fig:example} shows that`) will end up with normal Latin spaces around the reference number. One should instead use `图\nobreak\CJKecglue\ref{fig:example}\CJKecglue 展示了`. Furthermore, when the reference is followed by a punctuation mark (a full stop, for instance), one should use `图\nobreak\CJKecglue\ref{fig:example}。` (without the second `\CJKecglue`).

Putting everything together, we have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK} % loads fontspec internally
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Adventor}
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}

\makeatletter
\def\setCJKecglue@nnn#1#2#3{%
  \xeCJKsetup
    { xCJKecglue = {\hskip #1em plus #2em minus #3em\relax} }%
}
\newcommand*\setCJKecglue{%
  \ifnum\strcmp{\f@family}{\rmdefault}=0 %
    \ifnum\strcmp{\f@series}{\mddefault}=0 %
      \ifnum\strcmp{\f@shape}{\updefault}=0 %
        \setCJKecglue@nnn{0.09}{0.045}{0.03}%
      \else
        \setCJKecglue@nnn{0.5}{0.25}{0.167}%
      \fi
    \else
      \ifnum\strcmp{\f@shape}{\updefault}=0 %
        \setCJKecglue@nnn{1}{0.5}{0.333}%
      \else
        \setCJKecglue@nnn{1.5}{0.75}{0.5}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \else
    \ifnum\strcmp{\f@family}{\sfdefault}=0 %
      \ifnum\strcmp{\f@series}{\mddefault}=0 %
        \setCJKecglue@nnn{0.6}{0.3}{0.2}%
      \else
        \setCJKecglue@nnn{0.9}{0.45}{0.3}%
      \fi
    \else
      \setCJKecglue@nnn{0.2}{0.1}{0.067}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{everysel}
\EverySelectfont{\setCJKecglue}

\newcommand\test{%
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
  第1章 & \itshape 第1章 & \bfseries 第1章 & \bfseries\itshape 第1章 \\
  第 1 章 & \itshape 第 1 章 & \bfseries 第 1 章 & \bfseries\itshape 第 1 章 \\
  \end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand*\figref[1]{%
  图\nobreak\CJKecglue\ref{#1}\CJKecglue\ignorespaces
}
\newcommand*\figrefatend[1]{%
  图\nobreak\CJKecglue\ref{#1}\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\LARGE    \test\par
\sffamily \test\par
\ttfamily \test\par
\rmfamily
\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure to be referenced.}\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
Type ``1'': Figure~1 shows that\dots\par
图~1 展示了……(unbalanced spaces)\par
图\nobreak\CJKecglue1 展示了……(balanced spaces)\par
Use labels: Figure~\ref{fig:example} shows that\dots\par
图~\ref{fig:example} 展示了……(Latin spaces)\par
\figref{fig:example} 展示了……(correct spaces)\par
See Figure~\ref{fig:example}.\par
见\figref{fig:example}。(wrong space before full stop)\par
见 \figrefatend{fig:example} 。(no space before full stop)
\end{document}
```

[image: CJKecglue]

Special thanks to Qing Lee (maintainer of `xeCJK`) for suggesting `everysel`.