# \IfBold-command not working with fontspec anymore

Tags: fonts, fontspec

Following [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31649/detect-which-text-mode-normal-italic-bold-etc-is-currently-in-use) I created a command to check, if the bold font is currently selected.

This definitely used to work with `fontspec` some time ago (with TeXlive2018, if pdf-metadata is to be trusted), but not anymore (just ran `tlmgr` on my TeXlive2020 installation), as the following MWE shows:

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%-- Font setup
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Extension=.otf}
\setmainfont{XCharter} % <-- COMMENT THIS LINE!

%-- IfBold Command
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IfBold}{%
  \ifx\f@series\my@test@bx
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\my@test@bx}{bx}
\makeatother

%-- Define a command for K-theory
\newcommand{\Kay}{\IfBold{\ensuremath{\mathbold{K}}}{\ensuremath{K}}}
\robustify{\Kay}
\newcommand{\K}{\texorpdfstring{\Kay}{K}}

\begin{document}

\section*{I like \K-Theory}
This is the regular \K.
\textbf{This is \IfBold{bold}{non-bold} text.}
This is \IfBold{bold}{non-bold} text.

\end{document}
```

Is this a newly introduced bug or am I missing something?

Comment: it is not a bug, it is a change in LaTeX, but I have no time now ...

Comment: the easiest for now is to add `\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[sf]{bf}{b}` and to test for b: `\newcommand*{\my@test@bx}{b}`, but I will discuss a more generic solution to test for "bold context".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added `\IfFontSeriesContextTF` to the set of NFSS commands in the kernel so that one can reliably determine the  font series context even if, say in one font "bold" means semi-bold or ...

The first argument is either `bf` (am I typsetting in `\bfseries`?) or `md`(am I typsetting in `\mdseries?). It is an argument because one day there may be more series contexts available.

This is matching `\DeclareFontSeriesDefault` with which one can specify what "bold" means in `\sffamily`and so forth.

The code will appear during the next days in a new upload of the latex-dev format and will appear officially in the fall release 2020.

For now you can use the code below in place of the one you had in your example (somewhat longer, I know). Once latex-dev is out all you need is the definition for `\IfBold`, i.e., one line and then use

```
lualatex-dev  myfile
```

to compile it.

```
%-- IfBold Command
\makeatletter

\DeclareRobustCommand\IfFontSeriesContextTF[1]{%
  \expand@font@defaults
  \@font@series@contextfalse
  \def\requested@test@context{#1}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname ??def@ult\endcsname{\f@family}%
  \let\@elt\test@font@series@context
      \@meta@family@list
      \@elt{??}%
  \let\@elt\relax
  \if@font@series@context
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}

\def\test@font@series@context#1{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\csname #1def@ult\endcsname}%
  \ifx\f@family\reserved@a
    \let\@elt\@gobble
    \expandafter\ifx
                \csname\requested@test@context series@#1\endcsname\f@series
      \@font@series@contexttrue
    \else
      \expandafter\ifx
                  \csname\requested@test@context def@ult\endcsname\f@series
        \@font@series@contexttrue
  \fi\fi\fi
}

\newif\if@font@series@context

\newcommand\IfBold{\IfFontSeriesContextTF{bf}}

\makeatother
```

The result is:

[image]

Happy Texing

#### Update 2020/05

An implementation of this is now added to the development format of LaTeX and can be tested with `lualatex-dev` etc. It will be available in the next main release in fall 2020.

Comment: Sorry for an unrelated comment here. I would be really grateful if you could take a look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/546846 I think you, as a `xparse` developer can help.