# Test failing with long definitions

Tags: macros, conditionals

I was trying to define a command to behave differently when the text is italic, and I came across a difference between `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*` (or rather, I think, a behavior of `\long` definitions or of `\ifx`) that I don't understand. Basically, I define a command `\@it` to be `it`. Then, I want to check whether the text is italic or not using `\ifx\f@shape\@it`. This test works when `\@it` is defined using `\def` or `\newcommand*`, but not when `\@it` is defined using `\long\def` or `\newcommand`.

The following example should make everything clear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@defit{it}
\long\def\@longdefit{it}
\newcommand{\@ncit}{it}
\newcommand*{\@ncsit}{it}
\newcommand{\itcheck}{%
    \ifx\f@shape\@defit
        The test from \textnormal{\textbackslash\texttt{def}} found the italic shape.
    \else
        The test from \textnormal{\textbackslash\texttt{def}} did not found the italic shape.
    \fi\par
    \ifx\f@shape\@longdefit
        The test from \textnormal{\textbackslash\texttt{long}\textbackslash\texttt{def}} found the italic shape.
    \else
        The test from \textnormal{\textbackslash\texttt{long}\textbackslash\texttt{def}} did not found the italic shape.
    \fi\par
    \ifx\f@shape\@ncit
        The test from \textnormal{\textbackslash\texttt{newcommand}} found the italic shape.
    \else
        The test from \textnormal{\textbackslash\texttt{newcommand}} did not found the italic shape.
    \fi\par
    \ifx\f@shape\@ncsit
        The test from \textbackslash\textnormal{\texttt{newcommand*}} found the italic shape.
    \else
        The test from \textbackslash\textnormal{\texttt{newcommand*}} did not found the italic shape.
    \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\itshape\itcheck
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would have expected all tests to return true. Why is it not the case?

Comment: a long definition is never ifx equal to a non long one.

Comment: There is no reason to define a macro without parameter as long. Its behavior is exactly the same as no-long version of such macro. This is the reason, why \f@shape is defined as no-long. And your long definition of macros without parameters are irrelevant.

Comment: @wipet That seems indeed very logical. Thanks! I should probably just take the time to read a proper introduction to TeX one of these days.

Comment: ... to read a proper introduction to TeX: I wrote TeX in a Nutshell at these days. It is released at CTAN.

Comment: @wipet Interesting, I'll take a look! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With plain TeX, which is simpler: the code

```
\def\shortfoo{foo}
\long\def\longfoo{foo}

\ifx\shortfoo\longfoo\message{EQUAL}\else\message{DIFFERENT}\fi
\bye
```

will show `DIFFERENT` on the terminal.

Two macros are considered equal by `\ifx` if

1. their parameter text is the same;
2. their replacement text is the same;
3. their status with respect to `\long` and `\outer` is the same.

With e-TeX there is also another status to keep in mind: `\protected`.

If you're sure that your macros expand to character tokens, then

```
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\shortfoo}{\longfoo}=0
```

will return true. The `pdftex` primitive is called `\strcmp` in XeTeX and is missing from LuaTeX (the package `pdftexcmds` provides a Lua replacement). You can `\usepackage{pdftexcmds}` (or `\input pdftexcmds.sty` in plain TeX) and call it as `\pdf@strcmp` in the three engines.

Comment: Thanks! It seems clearer to me now. So I understand that the tests in my example failed because ``\f@shape`` is not ``\long``. Maybe this will seem to be a weird question for a more experienced user, but is there some kind of rule of thumb to know which commands are ``\long`` and which are not? I only knew the ``\f@shape`` command from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31660/201628), should I have guessed it was not ``\long``?