# Problem or feature: Package gfsartemisia-euler changes ú for ý when using \textsc

Tags: fonts, symbols, accents

I need to use the package gfsartemisia-euler to change the font of a book originally written with the palatine font to artemisia. My problem is as follows:

When I use `\textsc` or `\scshape` the character **ú** is replaced with **ý**

this happens only to  this character, all the others seem to work correctly. Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}
\scshape 
  Os números \\ 
  
  Os n\'umeros \\
  
  Nos capítulos, nas equações...\\ 
  
  É mesmo? Então faça com as próprias mãos  

  Höla e também H\"ola. (Exige tipa)
\end{document}
```

After compiling this file it produces the output

[image]

Comment: looks like a bug in the font. Report it to the author.

Comment: DON'T use `gfsartemisia-euler`. That's all. It's meant for Greek.

Comment: I get more wrong characters [see the last line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNmip.png)

Comment: Thank you my dears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a bug in the T1 version of GFSArtemisia. This is the part of the fonttable corresponding to Latin smallcaps:

[image]

You can see that Ý is listed twice while the first entry should be Ú. This should be reported to the maintainer so it can be fixed.

However, the OTF version from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/greek/gfs/gfsartemisia/opentype *does* have ú in smallcaps. So, if you want you can use a rather convoluted workaround to use this character with pdfLaTeX. The idea is to create a pdf file with only this character and set up a mapping in pdfLaTeX from ú to including this pdf, but only for smallcaps (and map to `\'u` for all other font styles).

Standalone ú smallcaps, compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. In the code below this file is referred to as `artemisscu.pdf`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GFSArtemisia.otf}
\begin{document}
\textsc{ú}
\end{document}
```

Mapping, using small caps detection from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31660:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IfSmallCapsTF}{%
  \ifx\f@shape\my@test@sc
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\newcommand*{\my@test@sc}{sc}
\makeatother

\newunicodechar{ú}{\IfSmallCapsTF{\raisebox{-0.02Ex}{\includegraphics[width=1.12Ex]{artemisscu}}}{\'u}}

\begin{document}
Os números

\scshape Os números
  
\Huge Os números
  
\tiny Os números
    
\normalsize Os n\'umeros
  
Nos capítulos, nas equações...
  
É mesmo? Então faça com as próprias mãos  

Höla e também H\"ola. (Exige tipa)

\normalfont
Os números
  
\end{document}
```

Note that the size and positioning of the graphic is set in `Ex` units so it scales with the font size.

Result:

[image]

Note that `\'u` itself is not mapped, so you need the actual ú as input to make it work.